# How to navigate to a cross domain web page through ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

The requirement of my application is to navigate to a cross domain page upon logging out. As probably CORS is not set(error: no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present) in the cross domain app, hence  response.sendRedirect(url) is not working from JAVA side. Now, realizing this cross domain barrier I did some research in UI side, explored many posts in internet and tried the following to navigate to a cross domain page from UI but with no avail. With Angularjs- 
`$http.jsonp('https://www.google.co.in/');`

With JQuery by including jquery.ajax-cross-origin.min.js-

```
$.ajax({crossOrigin: true,url: 'https://www.google.co.in/'});
```

In both cases it is giving error: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.
It looks like it is not expecting '<>' tags, but I am expecting it not to return any response (JSON or XML) but to redirect me to some other domain page (ex: https://www.google.co.in/). Can anybody help me resolving this by giving me an workable code which navigates me to a cross domain page (say: https://www.google.co.in/).

Comment: If you want to navigate there, why not use a simple redirection? `window.location = "http://www.google.co.in";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of `$.ajax({crossOrigin: true,url: 'https://www.google.co.in/'});` you have to use `window.location.href='https://www.google.co.in/'`

```
window.location.assign('url')
window.location='url'
window.location.href='url'
```

all of these will work for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working. Instead of researching on the CORS, I should have earlier asked this question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with my below code it is working:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: 'a.php?id=1',
    success:function(d){    
    if(d){
        window.location.href="http://www.google.com";

    }

    }

});
</script>
```